# Deserialization in Spring Cloud

Tags: spring-integration, amazon-kinesis, spring-cloud-stream, spring-integration-aws

I have a producer with following configuration for content-type

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        eventOut:
          destination: lab_csi
          content-type: application/json
```

On consumer side I use spring integration (KinesisMessageDrivenChannelAdapter) to route event to different channels.When I receive Message on listener class like below:

```
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "channelA")
    void handleMessage(Message<?> msg) {
        objectMapper.readValue(msg.getPayload(), MyEvent.class);
    }
```

the marshalling to MyEvent fails. In the stack error I can see that content-type is part of payload and payload is not still deserialized from json to POJO.

I am wondering how I can deserialize message before doing any other transformation. I don't find any method that I can set a MessageConverter to the adapter.

I appreciate your help.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like your producer is Spring Cloud Stream, but consumer is just plain `KinesisMessageDrivenChannelAdapter`. That is not clear why would one not use Spring Cloud Stream consumer as well, but anyway...

Your problem that SCSt producer serializes message headers together with the payload into the Kinesis record body. Just because AWS Kinesis doesn't support headers per se.

If you really are not interested in the headers on the consumer side, you can disable embedding headers on the producer side:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        eventOut:
          destination: lab_csi
        producer:
        headerMode: none
```

Otherwise you don't have choice on the plain `KinesisMessageDrivenChannelAdapter` side unless you use `EmbeddedHeaderUtils` manually.

Comment: Thanks Artem! You are totally right it does not make lots of sense to user spring cloud for producing and spring integration for consumer side. The reason is I found spring cloud producer easy to use for testing purpose. I wanted just to publish events to stream. Do you have any recommendation for producer side using spring integration?

Comment: `KinesisMessageHandler` `@Bean` with the `@ServiceActivator` to configure a channel to send to the AWS Kinesis. However you are almost there: just configure that `headerMode: none` on the producer side!